# Original filename in case of error in jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Using [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/), how is it possible to retrieve the original filename when an upload fails, in the `fileuploadfail` event handler?

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   ...
})
.on('fileuploadfail', function (evt, data) {
   // retrieve original filename
});
```

I did not find the answer in the documentation, and could not find anything in the event object or in the `data` parameter.

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` inside the function and you'll be able to know which parameter is holding the filename

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I did so, and could not find it. I logged `data` for 2 different files and could not spot any (relevant) difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the source code and found out that the function parameters doesn't pass the filename, so you can store the filename in a variable (for example) when you add the file and use it when there is an error:

```
var fileName;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    ....
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    fileName = data.files[0].name;
}).on('fileuploadfail', function (evt, data) {
    alert(fileName);
});
```

Edit: 
As written in the comments, apparently there is an option to get the filename in the `fail`   function by referring to `data.files[0].name` - Thanks @FlorentGeorges

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, when you select 2 files, the `*add` event is fired for both before the first `*fail` event is. So it ends up giving twice the same filename.

Comment: But actually, that gives me the answer, I can access `data.files[0].name` directly in the `*fail` event handler. Weirdly enough, when logging `data` into the console, or using `JSON.stringify()`, the property `files` shows as `[{}]`, so I thought it was an empty object (same behaviour in both handlers). Thanks!

Comment: If you update your answer to use `data.files[0].name`directly in `*fail`, I'll accept it :-)

Comment: @FlorentGeorges - You're too kind :) I've updated my answer but the credit deserve to you because I wasn't aware to that option. Thanks again